# Terraform: Azure Policies for SOC2 Type-2

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy

Using Terraform, I want to automate Azure Policy deployment. I know how to build and deploy Azure Policies using Terraform, but I'm not familiar with SOC2 Type-2. Do you have a policy implementation that covers SOC2 Type-2 which I can use or refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could argue that ISO 27001:2013 and SOC2 are attempting to provide the same objective, so you should look at the built-in ISO 27001 policies in Defender for Cloud > Manage Compliance Policies > [your subscription] > Add More Standards > ISO 27001:2013

ref:
[The difference between SOC 2 and ISO 27001](https://www.strikegraph.com/blog/difference-between-iso-27001-and-soc-2#:%7E:text=The%20main%20difference%20is%20that,program%20on%20a%20continual%20basis.)